# How do we get value from Json array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an response on calling a link like this:

```
 [{"err_status":"5000","err_message":null}]
```

How do we get the value from this array in swift 2. I used to get value usually by converting the json to NSdictionary and later

```
let generatedOTP = ((DictionaryVal["Yourvalue"]!) as? String)
```

But as its an array how is it possible.

Comment: your response is array then why you getting into nsarray ? update complete response if possible

Answer (score 1):

```
guard let array = json as? [[String: AnyObject]],
    dictionary = array.first else {
        return
}
//Now you can use dictionary as [String: AnyObject] or NSDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a JSON array. Why you put your array in a nsdictionary ? You should do that

```
var responseArray = NSArray()
responseArray = yourJsonArray as! NSArray // yourJsonArray is the original response you get
```

Now deal with this array. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift we can do like :

var arr = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: kNilOptions)!

var dict = arr[0]